# Does a Spiritual Weapon have all the other powers of the deity's weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

As a cleric who casts *spiritual weapon* to represent the weapon of their deity: can the weapon gain the ability to use spells that the deity's weapon can cast innately?

For instance, Oberon's shortsword has the ability to cast sunray once a day. Will the spiritual weapon be able to mimic this effect?

Comment: I removed the following text from your question as an edit, since it detracts from the focus of your question about the spell.  *And as a side question, what on earth is sunray? Closest i could find to a spell by that name is sunbeam.*  Can you cite the page number/reference for where you found that text?  (DMG, Basic Rules, Starter Set, etc).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The spell merely creates the appearance of the deity's weapon, if it were intended to do anything else it would be notated in the spell's entry.

> The weapon can take whatever form you choose. Clerics of deities who
>   are associated with a particular weapon (as St. Cuthbert is known for
>   his mace and Thor for his hammer) make this spell’s effect
>   **resemble** that weapon.

The spell merely does the damage indicated nothing more.